# How to render arrays of arrays in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Need to render arrays of arrays --> which contain objects

On JSX / HTML I should have for every sub-array one `<li></li>` tag, inside of that tag render objects from an array when this sub-array is rendered, I should move on next array and render next arrays in new `<li></li` tag

Problem in my implemntation is cus all sub-arrays are rendered inside of one `<li></li>`:

```
renderList = () => {
   return searchHelpers.logicalExamples.map((tagsArray) =>
      tagsArray.map((tag, i) => (
        <li className="label">
          <button>
            <span className="selected">{tag.name}</span>
          </button>
        </li>
      ))
    );
  };
```

This is object which is used for rendering lists:

```
const searchHelpers = {
  logicalExamples: [
    [
      { name: 'TX Group', tagTypeClass: '' },
      { name: 'AND', tagTypeClass: 'operator' },
      { name: 'Latest News', tagTypeClass: 'new-tag' }
    ],
    [
      { name: 'Pochettino', tagTypeClass: '' },
      { name: 'NOT', tagTypeClass: 'operator' },
      { name: 'Mourinho', tagTypeClass: '' }
    ],
    [
      { name: 'Cristobal Huet', tagTypeClass: '' },
      { name: 'OR', tagTypeClass: 'operator' },
      { name: 'Nico Hischier', tagTypeClass: '' }
    ],
    [
      { name: '(', tagTypeClass: 'new-tag' },
      { name: 'Climate Change', tagTypeClass: 'new-tag' },
      { name: ')', tagTypeClass: 'new-tag' }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Comment: What do exactly do you want to render? What do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: I want to every of this sub-arrays. 
And content of every sub-arrays should be inside of one `<li>`
  This is one sub-array [
      { name: 'TX Group', tagTypeClass: '' },
      { name: 'AND', tagTypeClass: 'operator' },
      { name: 'Latest News', tagTypeClass: 'new-tag' }
    ]

Comment: What HTML elements should be in each `<li>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use/create a `flatMap` function for this kind of scenario. I believe `lodash` has one, but it's tiny enough if you don't want to bundle in a library of that magnitude:

```
function flatMap(items, fn) {
  return items.reduce((result, item, i) => result.concat(fn(item, i)), []);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
renderList = () => flatMap(searchHelpers.logicalExamples, (tagsArray) =>
  tagsArray.map((tag, i) => (
    <li className="label">
      <button>
        <span className="selected">{tag.name}</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  ))
);
```

Don't forget to add a `key`, though!

**Update**:

OK, wasn't clear on what you needed before. All you'll need to do is:

```
renderList = () => searchHelpers.logicalExamples.map((tagsArray) => (
  <li className="label">
    {tagsArray.map((tag, i) => (
      <button>
        <span className="selected">{tag.name}</span>
      </button>
    ))}
  </li>
));
```

Comment: Hey, thx on answer, but still does not render as expected. Sub-arrays- items all are rendered as new `<li>`, I wanted to be for every array of objects one `<li>` wrapper.

Comment: That means I should have one `<li>and 3 buttons rendered inside of every <li>-element </li>`

Answer (score 2):

So you want each element of `logicalExamples` to render as an `<li>`. That looks like this:

```
renderList = () => {
   return searchHelpers.logicalExamples.map((tagsArray) =>
      <li className="label">
        // something goes here
      </li>
    );
  };
```

And for each element of `tagsArray` you want a `<button>`:

```
renderList = () => {
   return searchHelpers.logicalExamples.map((tagsArray) =>
      <li className="label">
        {tagsArray.map((tag, i) => (
          <button>
            <span className="selected">{tag.name}</span>
          </button>
        }
      ))
      </li>
    );
  };
```